# How to pass an array of textBox to another form in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'am a 2 months c# studient.

I have 3 textBox array defined in a form and I want pass to program.cs

Those names below are declared as public and it works in the form where they are declared but as I call same thing from other forms, I want to put it in program.cs under the public GeneralMethodes

```
        _textBox = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9 };
        _textBox1 = new TextBox[] { textBox10, textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16, textBox17, textBox18 };
        _textBox2 = new TextBox[] { dateTxt, deadLineTxt, qtyprodTxt };
```

In program.cs I have the code below:

```
public static void EraseTextBox(Form[] MyBox, Form[] MyBox1)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            MyBox[i].Text = "";
            MyBox1[i].Text = "";
        }
```

In my caller form I have this code:

```
GeneralMethodes.EraseTextBox(_textBox, _textBox1); // This works if the code is in the same form.
```

I tried with Type[], string[],Array[],Object[],object[]  but they don't work and don't accept .Text except Form.

What should I put for defining this array in EraseTextBox(? MyBox, ? MyBox1) ?

Comment: I would recommend that you use an array of `Controls` instead.

Comment: __textBox = new TextBox[]_ so why you want to pass something different? they are all TextBox[] arrays. of course the EraseTextBox method should declare three parameters of type TextBox[]

Comment: Apologise from everyone I did not use Textbox[] :) I've tried just after it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void EraseTextBox(TextBox[] MyBox, TextBox[] MyBox1)

{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        MyBox[i].Text = "";
        MyBox1[i].Text = "";
    }
```

Probably your error is that you're using Form[] instead of TextBox[] on EraseTextBox

Comment: Thank you. I saw it just after I posted. I passed more then hour and tried all possibilities except textBox :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `EraseTextBox` should accept a `TextBox[]`.

Besides just modifying the type of the array parameter, in `EraseTextBox` you should really be going off of the length of the array instead of a hardcoded upper limit.  The `EraseTextBox` function should be using the length of the array to determine when to stop iterating.  With a hard coded upper limit, you can use the code and either not clear all the text boxes, or get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You should also consider not accepting two arrays.  What happens when the length of one array does not match the other, one or the other will not be entirely cleared, or an exception could occur.

```
public static void EraseTextBoxes(TextBox[] boxes)
{ 
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.Length; ++i)
        boxes[i].Text = "";
}
```

Then you call it like so:

```
EraseTextBoxes(_textBox);
EraseTextBoxes(_textBox1);
```

Answer (score -1):

An array is a collection of objects with a certain type.
You said you want an array of text boxes, so you want to declare an array that can hold many `TextBox`es.

For example,

```
TextBox[] _textBoxes = new TextBox[3];
```

would create an array that can hold 4 `TextBox`es.

In your case, change `Form[] MyBox` to `TextBox[] MyBox`.

Comment: Your created array holds 3 not 4 items.